# Distributed algorithms for finding n largest elements

Tags: distributed-systems

It's easy to come up with a simple distributed algorithms for finding the maximum element in a set (totally ordered): Divide and conquer.

There are a few publications that present algorithms for distributed maximum-finding. The challenge is to pass the  fewest messages between nodes.

**Does anyone know of algorithms that tackle the same problem for the distributed "n-largest-finding" problem?**

A naive solution is a repeated application of a distributed maximum-finding algorithm by successively slicing off the maximums. Another naive solution is to use a distributed sort. These two are probably not even that bad in the extreme cases (very small n, very large n). But how about finding the 10% largest elements (the top decile)?

For reference: There's a question on SO, [CUDA: Finding the N largest values of a sparse array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241568/cuda-finding-the-n-largest-values-of-a-sparse-array), which leads to just using a sort.